# Unable to access variable

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have two external Javascript files. I declared a variable in one file and I am trying to access the variable from other. When I try to access it, it returns `undefined`.

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

**script1**:

```
$(function(){

    var myvar=35;
});
```

**script2**:

```
$(function(){

    alert(myvar); //this line causing error undefined.

});
```

Comment: Where are you defining `myVar`? Is it within a function?

Comment: Are you certain script1 is loaded? If not, try to include an alert statement in script1 and see if it fires, or even better, check if there are any 404 responses.

Comment: are you sure it's called srcipt1 and not script1?

Comment: sure I am using developer tools with breakpoints first initialize myvar  then only it is using in script

Comment: sorry its not possible to put all code

Comment: If you define the variable using the `var` keyword, it's not global. Please check the filenames (e.g. I guess there should be a file extension like **.js**)

Comment: @Odi - That's not correct. `var` used _outside_ of a function creates a global variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, you're right. It's local to the defined scope, if this happens to be the global scope the variable is of course global. My bad :(

Comment: see the edits there might be a problem with using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable isn't global. You've declared it inside a function so it is local to that function. You need to move the `var` statement *outside* your document ready function:

```
var myvar=35;

$(function(){
    // other document ready stuff here, including
    // using or assigning a value to myvar if needed
});
```

Then it will be globally scoped and can be accessed from other script files (as long as they're included after the one where it's declared).

If you don't know the value to assign until the document ready then do this:

```
var myvar;       // declare variable

$(function(){
    myvar = 35;  // assign value
});
```

Since you don't try to use the value until the other script's document ready handler runs this would be fine.

Comment: if i declared function on ready function those are also not accesseble?????????????

Comment: Anything declared inside another function is local to that function. So if you have declared functions inside your ready handler but actually want them to be global you'd need to move those function declarations outside the same as for `myvar`.

Answer (score 1):

Script1.js

```
  var i=10;
```

Script2.js

```
  function call(){
      alert(i);
  }
```

Sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Script1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Script2.js" ></script>
<script>
</script>
<BODY onload='call();'>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: may be it helps for when i use without jquery

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answers, your code would work if you dropped the 'var' keyword in the first javascript file . . . .

Dropping 'var' assigns the value to the global variable,  and if one doesn't exist, a global variable would be created . . .so, it will be same as a global myvar

```
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
```

script1:

```
$(function(){


myvar=35;

});
```

script2:

```
$(function(){

alert(myvar); //this will work

});
```