# function accessing between two or more scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scope

I have two scripts and I need to use script1 function in script2. Whats the best way to do it and Is there any simplification using prototype to access function in more scripts. I am using jquery.

script1

```
$(function(){
 function  process(){
// some code
}
})
```

script2

```
$(function(){

// I would like to use the process function here

}
```

Comment: Learn javascript and after that jquery

Comment: This is pretty basic and there are probably tons of dupes here already, you should search before making a question. Also, reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Script1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Script2.js" ></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <BODY onload='calling();'>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Scrip1.jc

```
function call(){
    alert("Hi i am called from script2");
}
```

Scrip2.js

```
function calling(){
    call();
}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript functions as variables. So just reread your question about the same stuff about variables - [Unable to access variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048863/unable-to-access-variable)

So just do so your function will be available from global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the function declaration outside the ready event handler, that will make it globally available.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: use objects:

```
var Ob = {
   process: function(callback) {
     callback();
   }
}
```

script1

```
$(function(){
 Ob.process(function(){
      ... // code
   });
});
```

script 2 (do same)

```
$(function(){
 Ob.process(function(){
      ... //another code
   });
});
```

If you are using same `process` function (means same body content, make same thing in both script) then

```
var Ob = {
   process: function() {
     ...//put code
   }
}
```

script1

```
$(function(){
 Ob.process();
});
```

script 2 (do same)

```
$(function(){
 Ob.process();
});
```

Comment: I know this but i am searching for other --|-

Comment: You knew this ? It is most reliable than your example.